# how to stop google crawl unexisting page

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-crawler

When I was developing my site. I made a typo in one place, for example, all my pages are dir1/dir2/page.htm/par1-par2, but my typo was dir1/dir2/page/par1-par2 (note: without .htm).

It was in production for 1 day only, but Google is keep crawling those links. How to stop Google doing that?

By the way, that's not 1 page, but hundreds or thousands of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use robots.txt to deny access to this page (url)

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

test robots.txt here : http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check/

```
patterns must begin with / because robots.txt patterns always match absolute URLs. 
* matches zero or more of any character. 
$ at the end of a pattern matches the end of the URL; elsewhere $ matches itself. 
* at the end of a pattern is redundant, because robots.txt patterns always match any URL which begins with the pattern.
```

Comment: Depending on other things, this should work. I edit the answer with a complement

Comment: What I want is block anything in /subdir/(not ending with .htm)/whatever. How to do that? Ty

Comment: if pattern-matching works, this solution should work. just afraid to write anything wrong since never done before.

Comment: Check more here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: ending with .htm? in my case, all links like /*.htm/1x-2x

Comment: Use this site to check if you robots works http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check/

Comment: @likeforex.com build your robots and test here http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check/

Comment: i tested and seems this works: Allow:/subdir/*.htm/ Disallow:/subdir/* Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the page exists (perhaps because your using mod_rewrite) and rendering a custom page not found but not sending a http 410 Gone header `header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone");` then google wont know its been removed and index it just the same.

You need to add the proper headers or remove the page or not render your own 404, so it hits your servers 404, then google will remove the page from the index, also the removal of the page wont happen over night:

You could also add the url to a robots.txt file also this is not guaranteed to remove the page from the index, you could contact google as others have said but then its not guaranteed to get a response or removal.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /dir1/dir2/page/par1-par2
```

Good luck.

Comment: yes. used htaccess rewrite, so those pages never been there! and page is a variable, so does par1-par2. just lots of pages. have to using pattern-matching

Comment: google sees them as a page, when you visit the pages in question if it outputs anything other then a 404 not found or a 410 http header its indexed. You could use Disallow: /dir1/ and then any page up the url tree wont get indexed. hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Google has a form where you can ask it to remove a page from its index.

Check out the info at this link:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734